# Reciprocal vs Reflexive

Tags: morphology, terminology

In languages where the reflexive and reciprocal meaning is expressed with one single suffix, is the reciprocal considered a kind of reflexive suffix or is the reflexive a kind of reciprocal?

Comment: Please explain, what you expect to hear. Does the linguistic tradition give the same suffix different names when it is used differently? Do people understand whether the action is directed at the actor only or not? Do you have any pearticular languages in mind?

Comment: Well ,i meant the first suggestion .

Comment: You should add that to the question (and consequently delete the related comments).

Comment: I don't see why a suffix that is reciprocal in some contexts and reflexive in others would not simply be called a reflexive/reciprocal suffix.  It just doesn't make sense to consider a reflexive morpheme to be a type of reciprocal morpheme or visa versa.   A better question might be "How do linguists customarily gloss a morpheme that conveys either 'reflexive' or 'reciprocal' depending on context?".